# How to read the data from SysBench And UnixBench when testing VPS

Tags: linux, vps, benchmark

i want to test several linux VPS using bench mark tools 
as i reead there are 2 indestry standart tools called unixBench and SysBench
I compiled them and executed them on the VPS 
And i have results :
SysBench:( 4 CPU)

```
./sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 --num-threads=4 run
```

The result :

```
General statistics:
    total time:                          3.222s
    total number of events:              10000

Latency (ms):
         min:                                  1.64
         avg:                                  5.76
         max:                                  6.19
         95th percentile:                      3.00
         sum:                              60000.86

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           30000.0000/2.00
    execution time (avg/stddev):   8.0002/0.00
```

from reading i know that the important info is in :  total time: 3.222s
ok .. but compared to what ? 
how can i know that this is good result ? 
also what about the other parameters ? like 95th percentile 
what does it means ?

Now running UnixBench ( 4 CPU )

```
./Run -c 4
```

The result :

```
BYTE UNIX Benchmarks (Version 5.1.3)

   System: ip-10-0-1-48: GNU/Linux
   OS: GNU/Linux -- 3.14.48-33.39.amzn1.x86_64 -- #1 SMP Tue Jul 14 23:43:07 UTC 2015
   Machine: x86_64 (x86_64)
   Language: en_US.UTF-8 (charmap="UTF-8", collate="UTF-8")
   CPU 0:  info .. 
   CPU 1:  info .. 
   CPU 2:  info .. 
   CPU 3:  info .. 


------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark Run: Wed Apr 12 2017 
4 CPUs in system; running 4 parallel copies of tests

Dhrystone 2 using register variables       74325935.8 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Double-Precision Whetstone                    13710.8 MWIPS (9.9 s, 7 samples)
Execl Throughput                               3528.0 lps   (30.0 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 1024 bufsize 2000 maxblocks        422092.9 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 256 bufsize 500 maxblocks          107334.5 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 4096 bufsize 8000 maxblocks       1485937.1 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
Pipe Throughput                              998109.2 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Pipe-based Context Switching                 162959.5 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Process Creation                               7151.7 lps   (30.0 s, 2 samples)
Shell Scripts (1 concurrent)                   6494.3 lpm   (60.0 s, 2 samples)
Shell Scripts (8 concurrent)                    880.4 lpm   (60.1 s, 2 samples)
System Call Overhead                         900145.3 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)

System Benchmarks Index Values               BASELINE       RESULT    INDEX
Dhrystone 2 using register variables         116700.0   74325935.8   6369.0
Double-Precision Whetstone                       55.0      13710.8   2492.9
Execl Throughput                                 43.0       3528.0    820.5
File Copy 1024 bufsize 2000 maxblocks          3960.0     422092.9   1065.9
File Copy 256 bufsize 500 maxblocks            1655.0     107334.5    648.5
File Copy 4096 bufsize 8000 maxblocks          5800.0    1485937.1   2562.0
Pipe Throughput                               12440.0     998109.2    802.3
Pipe-based Context Switching                   4000.0     162959.5    407.4
Process Creation                                126.0       7151.7    567.6
Shell Scripts (1 concurrent)                     42.4       6494.3   1531.7
Shell Scripts (8 concurrent)                      6.0        880.4   1467.3
System Call Overhead                          15000.0     900145.3    600.1
                                                                   ========
System Benchmarks Index Score                                        1157.3
```

Here again i know i should look at the :
System Benchmarks Index Score                                        1157.3

but again the question raised this result is compared to what ? 
how should i know if this total result is good ? bad ? average ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [USAGE](https://github.com/kdlucas/byte-unixbench/blob/master/UnixBench/USAGE) file of UnixBench,

> Interpreting the results of these tests is tricky, and totally depends on what you're trying to measure.

In your case you want to "test several linux VPS" so for starters you can rank them according to the index (or according to specific indicators you can find in the test, if you know exactly what you are looking for).

In order to know how well a machine performs "in general" (that is to say, in comparison to all machines ever used for similar needs), one would need a large database reporting benchmarks categorized by hardware and OS (and maybe other specs).
It seems that http://linux-bench.com/ is a step towards this, which would be useful not only to know the above, but also to confirm suspicion of hardware not working as well as it should. Unfortunately, in my opinion the current "results" section is not rich enough, contains aberrant results, and does not indicate enough information about the different systems tested.